# How to monitor how many bytes have been already processed by the Could Text-to-Speech API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

I am using Google Cloud Text-to-Speech API. It offers 1M bytes free processing for some voices (e.g. Neural2) and 100k for others (e.g. Studio), every month.
I'd love to know how many bytes I already consumed this month, but I can't find any way to monitor that.
In the console, all data and quotas refer to requests per minute, there's no "data usage monitor".
Anybody has an idea of where and how I could find this information?

Also: I'm not sure if these usage quotas are cumulative or exclusive. If for example I use 50k of Studio bytes, do I still get to use 1M bytes of Neural2, or only 500k?

I am quite confused :D

I tried googling, looking up here on Stack Overflow, asking ChatGPT, but I couldn't find any clear answers.
The only useful hint so far has been that maybe "billing" will reveal how many bytes I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to https://console.cloud.google.com/billing, navigate to your billing section. Once there, you should find the report section, and in the filters, select group by 'SKU.' This should display what you have consumed.

Comment: Hi Filipe,
thank you for your answer, I think it's the right one. I had checked there, but there was no data. I guessed it only needed some time to updated it.
On the other hand, I can only see two kinds of voices: wavenet and standard. The other tipologies (Neural, Studio and Polyglot) are missing.
Do you happen to have any idea what that means?
From the consumption I think "Studio" must be a subtype of "wavenet", but then I don't understand how I should interpret the fact that they have different free quotas (Wavenet has 1M and Studio 100.000).